# Can't Run Simulator

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, codenameone

I haven't been coding for a little while, and so I fired up Eclipse, updated the plugin and Eclipse, and now when I try to launch the simulator I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack

Exception Details:
Location: javax/swing/JScrollBar.getAccessibleContext()Ljavax/accessibility/AccessibleContext; @16: putfield
Reason:    
    Type 'javax/swing/JScrollBar$AccessibleJScrollBar' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'javax/accessibility/AccessibleContext'
Current Frame:
    bci: @16
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'javax/swing/JScrollBar' }
    stack: { 'javax/swing/JScrollBar', 'javax/swing/JScrollBar$AccessibleJScrollBar' }
Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 001f c700 0f2a bb00 6259 2ab7 0063
    0x0000010: b500 1f2a b400 1fb0                    
Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@19)

at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.<init>(JavaSEPort.java:411)
at com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory.createImplementation(ImplementationFactory.java:69)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.init(Display.java:475)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1.run(Executor.java:112)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Do I need to uninstall Eclipse and re-install it? Anyone else has this problem? I tried a few apps that all used to work, and they all do this.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce it with my Eclipse version on a Mac and was unable to do so. It's a problem that was just reported by 2 other developers so it's probably a recent issue. Unfortunately it looks like a JDK related bug as the failure is literally in the bytecode of the JDK. Which version of Eclipse are you using? Can you try with Neon 2?

Comment: I reported the same issue and I am using Eclipse Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) Build id: 20171005-1200.  The only installed JRE in Eclipse is 1.8.0_144.

Comment: I'm assuming you are all using Windows. Can you try an older JDK update before 144?

Comment: Eclipse is using JRE 144, but I have my JAVA_HOME pointing to a 131 JDK.

Comment: That might be a problem. JDK versions must be 100% consistent. Try pointing eclipse at the older JDK

Comment: It was working on Oxygen until recently, I'm using a Mac. I'll check which JDK things are pointing to.

Comment: If you revert to Oxygen does it start working again? I wasn't able to reproduce it on my developer machine and people started having it "suddenly" so I'm assuming a recent update either to the JDK or Eclipse triggered it as it has been a while since we released the plugin update

Comment: Seems to work with Neon.3 Release (4.6.3). I didn't try with an earlier Oxygen version, but I imagine it would work and that something happened in the latest version that broke it.

Comment: Also just tried it with Oxygen (4.7), and it works on that version as well. Something broke in 4.7.1 or 4.7.1a.

Comment: We also pushed a lib update over the weekend so that might be related although I don't see how.

Comment: I've just had a clean install on a new PC with Eclipse and JRE/JDK 1.8.0_152. I get this too. Any idea what the last working version of Java was so I don't spend the next half a day installing different versions until I find one that works?

Comment: Try an earlier Eclipse version, 4.7 or earlier. I don't think it's the Java version.

Comment: I just posted a workaround I was able to find, still working on the issue in the Eclipse tracker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** I have a workaround which I don't fully understand. Right click the `Simulator*.launch` file and select `Run As` -> `Run Configurations`. There select the simulator entry and select classpath:

[image]

In the bootstrap entries remove the JRE System Library and press run. Once you do that running and debugging should work as before.

Below is my (still applicable at this time) answer.

I was able to reproduce this and it happens on a Mac too. This looks like an Eclipse bug and I've filed an issue here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526441 Feel free to upvote/comment on the issue so we might get a faster resolution on this.

I'm trying to find a workaround but I'm not really sure where to begin right now as this is pretty deep in the JVM/IDE. I added eclipse tags to the question hoping someone from the eclipse community has a better idea.