# Error when trying to start a Codenameone demo app

Tags: java, codenameone

Can anybody please help?

On Windows 10, 64bit system.
I have just installed jre8 and eclipse and codenameone. Then i'd like to run a demo app (CameraDemo.java). it builds fine but crash with tis error on startup:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    javax/swing/JScrollBar.getAccessibleContext()Ljavax/accessibility/AccessibleContext; @16: putfield
  Reason:
    Type 'javax/swing/JScrollBar$AccessibleJScrollBar' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'javax/accessibility/AccessibleContext'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @16
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'javax/swing/JScrollBar' }
    stack: { 'javax/swing/JScrollBar', 'javax/swing/JScrollBar$AccessibleJScrollBar' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 011b c700 0f2a bb00 a959 2ab7 0144
    0x0000010: b501 1b2a b401 1bb0                    
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@19)

    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.<init>(JavaSEPort.java:365)
    at com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory.createImplementation(ImplementationFactory.java:69)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.init(Display.java:565)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1.run(Executor.java:112)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have done some futher research. It's the same with all codenameonde demos and even if I make my own little codenameone project, but for any of my java projects there's no problem at all.
So it seem to be related to codenameone.

Comment: Is your Codename One plugin up-to-date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822921/cant-run-simulator

Comment: I just downloaded it and installed it 2 days ago via the marketplace

Comment: I'm using eclipse Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200

Comment: My jre is JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_151"

Comment: Can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822921/cant-run-simulator and try to answer my questions in the comments. It seems to be a recent issue either with the JDK or Eclipse install. Since people reported that Oxygen was working for them I suggest reverting to an older version of Java which might be the reason.

Comment: It seem to work now. I first changed the JRE to build 131 and it still produced the same error. Then I changed til Eclipse to Oxygen 4.7- and then now it seem to work fine.
Thank you! Shai.