# Codename One: Bad type on operand stack javax/swing/JScrollBar.getAccessibleContext()

Tags: java, eclipse, codenameone

Checking my Codename One App (which has been working flawlessly for over a year now) I recognized that it won't start anymore. As I tried to start it in Eclipse, I got the following stack trace:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
>       Exception Details:
>         Location:
>           javax/swing/JScrollBar.getAccessibleContext()Ljavax/accessibility/AccessibleContext; @16: putfield
>         Reason:
>           Type 'javax/swing/JScrollBar$AccessibleJScrollBar' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'javax/accessibility/AccessibleContext'
>         Current Frame:
>           bci: @16
>           flags: { }
>           locals: { 'javax/swing/JScrollBar' }
>           stack: { 'javax/swing/JScrollBar', 'javax/swing/JScrollBar$AccessibleJScrollBar' }
>         Bytecode:
>           0x0000000: 2ab4 001f c700 0f2a bb00 6259 2ab7 0063
>           0x0000010: b500 1f2a b400 1fb0
>         Stackmap Table:
>           same_frame(@19)
>       at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.(JavaSEPort.java:411)
>       at com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory.createImplementation(ImplementationFactory.java:69)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Display.init(Display.java:475)
>       at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1.run(Executor.java:112)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Now for the Problem: I do not use the `java.swing.JScrollBar` anywhere in my code. I even searched through all of my classes. I really have no clue, how to fix this problem. The StackTrace doesn't even refer to a class written by me, just Java and CodenameOne Classes. Is this a bug in CO1 or is it my code?

I'am wondering why it came up after the app running for a good year without a fault and all of a sudden (without updating the app in any way) it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Please provide code so we can help. Here we can only answer "you have a Bad type on operand stack".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an Eclipse related [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526441). Probably some class loading problem where different JREs are mixed up.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926736/9309732) contains a work-around, which is also mentioned in the Eclipse issue.

Comment: FYI this was fixed in newer versions of the plugins for newly created projects but we can't fix older projects automatically